# How to delete an object in SwiftUI which is marked with @ObjectBinding?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to delete an object which is marked as `@ObjectBinding`, in order to clean up some `TextFields` for example.

I tried to set the object reference to nil, but it didn't work.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class A: BindableObject {
    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

    var text = "" { didSet { didChange.send() } }
}

class B {
    var property = "asdf"
}

struct DetailView : View {
    @ObjectBinding var myObject: A = A()    //@ObjectBinding var myObject: A? = A() -> Gives an error.
    @State var mySecondObject: B? = B()

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            TextField($myObject.text, placeholder: Text("Enter some text"))
            Button(action: {
                self.test()
            }) {
                Text("Clean up")
            }
        }
    }

    func test() {
        //myObject = nil
        mySecondObject = nil
    }
}
```

If I try to use an optional with `@ObjectBinding`, I'm getting the Error

> "Cannot convert the value of type 'ObjectBinding' to specified type
>   'A?'".

It just works with `@State`.

Regards

Comment: After hitting "clean up", the TextField still needs a binding. Even if you could make myObject = nil, then what would happen to poor TextField? You should probably create a method inside the type A, called cleanup() that takes care of cleaning up your model (i.e., make text = ""). You then call it every time you tap on Clean up.

Comment: I posted an example for my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```swift
class A: BindableObject {
    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

    var form = FormData() { didSet { didChange.send() } }

    struct FormData {
        var firstname = ""
        var lastname  = ""
    }

    func cleanup() {
        form = FormData()
    }
}

struct DetailView : View {
    @ObjectBinding var myObject: A = A()

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            TextField($myObject.form.firstname, placeholder: Text("Enter firstname"))
            TextField($myObject.form.lastname, placeholder: Text("Enter lastname"))
            Button(action: {
                self.myObject.cleanup()
            }) {
                Text("Clean up")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I absolutely agree with [@kontiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7786555/kontiki) , but you should remember to don't use @State when variable can get outside. @ObjectBinding right way in this case. Also all new way of memory management already include optional(weak) if they need it.

Check [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/whats-the-difference-between-objectbinding-state-and-environmentobject) to get more information about memory management in SwiftUI

Thats how to use @ObjectBinding

```
struct DetailView : View {
    @ObjectBinding var myObject: A
```

and

```
DetailView(myObject: A())
```